# Responsive navigation, can't define width/height in percent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I'm trying to build a responsive navigation menu that'll scale with media queries.

The problem is (and it's a stupid one I can't work out) that I can't get the a tags to appear as block level elements(I think).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="navbuttons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Expertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Capabilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div> <!-- end div navbuttons -->
```

And the CSS:

```
.navbuttons {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    transition:all .2s linear; 
    -o-transition:all .2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:all .2s linear; 
    -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
}

.navbuttons ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float: left;
}

.navbuttons li {
    float:left;
}

.navbuttons li a {
    background: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 16.5%;
}
```

Yet, if I use px to define width/height, I can get it looking roughly how I want (though it obviously isn't fluid, like I need).

```
.navbuttons {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    transition:all .2s linear; 
    -o-transition:all .2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:all .2s linear; 
    -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
}

.navbuttons ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float: left;
}

.navbuttons li {
    float:left;
}

.navbuttons li a {
    background: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Where am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The A tags are indeed block level once you specify `display: block;` on them, however, the 16.5% is calculated from their natural width (i.e. their 100% width based on the inner text).

Depending on your needs, you may want to remove the width parameter and simply add padding. See: http://jsfiddle.net/bLS6B/. This way, the width is dependent on the navigation text, not some preset width. Alternatively, you can specify 120% which has a similar effect.

Comment: This guy has done it here : http://designshack.net/articles/css/code-a-responsive-navigation-menu/
I can't get it to work in a similar way though.

Comment: There are many differences between your code and his. For one, he doesn't float the LIs to the left. Try removing that for starters. http://jsfiddle.net/bLS6B/2/

Comment: @DerekHunziker great man...wish I could accept this answer..but Q. is not mine +1...thanks